# Writing: Operation not permitted issue while working pdf

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, swift2

i am working on PDF File to read and write using Core Text . 
Below code is to draw content on the PDF file .

```
let fileName = "pdffilename.pdf"
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as NSString
    let pathForPDF = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString(fileName)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pathForPDF, CGRectZero, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0,612,792), nil)
    pagedataforPortaits()
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

This Code is working absolutely fine of simulator but when i am using a real device i am getting an Error

```
<Error>: CGDataConsumerCreateWithFilename: failed to open `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CADA69EB-8879-45EE-BBE0-477AC810BB86/Documentspdffilename.pdf' for writing: Operation not permitted.
deflateEnd: error -3: (null).
deflateEnd: error -3: (null).
<Error>: CGPDFContextCreate: failed to create PDF context delegate.
```

Any Suggestions ??

Comment: Are you able to fix that issue /

Answer (score 0):

The path string needs a `"/"` separator between the documents directory and file name.

**Swift 5.1:**

```
let fileName = "pdffilename.pdf"
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let pathForPDF = documentsDirectory + "/" + fileName
```